# asp.net webforms registering javascript from user control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a abstract user control that provides common functionality across a few controls, it requires some javascript functions to hook up client side events, what is the best way to inject this javascript.

I did have a look at ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock but it seems that this is aimed at using UpdatePanels and the like which I am not doing, would this still work correctly if all I want to do is have this javascript located in a single place and rendered from the abstract user control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to include a javascript file in the page header, like this:

```
LiteralControl jsResource = new LiteralControl();
jsResource.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"js/mini-template-control.js\"></script>";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(jsResource);

HtmlLink stylesLink = new HtmlLink();
stylesLink.Attributes["rel"] = "stylesheet";
stylesLink.Attributes["type"] = "text/css";
stylesLink.Href = "css/mini-template-control.css";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(stylesLink);
```

Here is a similar question I found:

[Programmatically adding Javascript File to User Control in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521639/programmatically-adding-javascript-file-to-user-control-in-net)

Answer (score 2):

If you are not rendering in an async postback, then use the ClientScriptManager's [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtee7dtx.aspx) instead. You can access this from the [Page.ClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.clientscript.aspx) property. If you use the ScriptManager's method, it should work, but it would require that the page have a ScriptManager on it in addition to your control.